Kotlin Multiplatform - Windows MSI build is missing start menu option
I'm building a Kotlin KMM app (JVM target with Compose UI). For Windows, the targets TargetFormat.exe and TargetFormat.Msi both create installers, but both don't include an option to add Start Menu Entries. This means that a user needs to manually locate the app exe in the Program Files folder to use it, which is not a good solution. The build seems to make use of jpackage, which has options for start menu entries (e.g. --win-menu), that don't seem to be enabled by default for the KMM targets.
My question is: How can I add those options in my build.gradle? Unfortunately the build system still seems poorly documented for KMM :(
build.gradle excerpt:
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi)
            packageName = "..."
            packageVersion = "..."
            description = "..."
            copyright = "..."
            vendor = "..."

            macOS {
                iconFile.set(project.file("app_icon.icns"))
            }

            windows {
                iconFile.set(project.file("app_icon.png"))
            }

            linux {
                iconFile.set(project.file("app_icon.png"))
            }
        }
    }
}



Answering my own question, configuring a menu entry is quite simple actually:
windows {
    ...
    menu = true
    menuGroup = "My Company Name"
    ...
}

